# How to add static methods inside "Program" in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 with .NET 6.0 framework. The following no longer exists and I usually write whatever that'll be inside this static void Main method directly in the "Program" that is automatically generated when creating a new project.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

However, if I need to have some static methods outside the static void Main method, it won't work to just write them inside "Program". How can I add these static methods then?

Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: It still exists; you can add it.

Comment: Did you read the first line, when creating a console program?  It's like: "// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information"   someone did put it there with a reason.

Comment: ' if I need to have some static methods outside the static void Main method, it won't work'. Yes it will. Maybe you should share the code you have written so we can see what your problem is

Answer (score 1):

You are probably referring to ["top level statements"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements). This is when you dispense with the whole main method, since it is just boilerplate, and just write code directly in a code file.

If you need any helper methods you should just add a new code file and add the methods in a static class:

```
public static class MyHelpers{
    public static int MyAddMethod(int a, int b) => a + b;
}
```

And just call it like `MyHelpers.MyAddMethod(1, 2)`.

As gunr2171 points out, you can also put classes at the end of your top-level file. But for your own and others sanity I would highly recommend trying to stick with one class per file.

Comment: And I'd _recommend_ that the helper class go into its own file, though you can put everything into Program [if you make the class last](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rxODUy).